# Sending rabbitmq events to logstash and elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am trying to build a log aggregator from various processes/services.
To do this I am planning to write logs to both the disk and also to a dedicated rabbit queue for each service.

I would then configure a logstash instance to listen to these rabbit queue, which it would then forward to elastic and
I would be able to view these using the Kibana dashboard.

I have followed various tutorials for this and have got the ELK stack working on my Windows machine.
I even installed the winbeats plugin for logstash and was able to see the eventlogs in Kibana dashboard.

Now then, I wanted to replace the `winbeats` part with `rabbitmq` and now have this below configuration in my `logstash` config.

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "localhost" 
        queue => "MyLogQueue"
        exchange => "MyLogExchange" 
        durable => true
        subscription_retry_interval_seconds => 5 
        }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

and this is the code I am using to publish messages to the queue

```
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MyLogQueue", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        var timer = new Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds);

        string[] logBag = {"Info", "Trace", "Warn", "Error" };
        var randomIndex = new Random(0) ;

        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var message = logBag[randomIndex.Next(0, logBag.Length -1)] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("R");
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "MyLogExchange", routingKey: "MyLogQueue", basicProperties: null, body: body);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0}", message);   
        };

        timer.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        timer.Stop();
    }
```

I can see that logstash instance is starting properly but am not able to view
the message I send to the queue in `Kibana`.
The code which is publishing the message is working fine and I can read the message from my other sample rabbit queue consumer.
I just get an empty json file when I navigate to `http://localhost:9200/logstash-*`

Comment: Try running logstash with `--verbose` or even `--debug` to see if Logstash shows any info regarding the rabbitmq queue, do you see anything in your ES log?

Comment: Also take a look to the logs from Logstash and add to your question the parts that seem relevant

Comment: I don't see anything evident in the logs either.